# Unable to send email based on CRON expression

Tags: c#, .net-core, cron, job-scheduling

I have a background service which runs every hour, will read the cron expression from my table
and would like to send an email at the exact time when the date time from the cron expression reaches or past the current date time :

```
if(DateTime.Now >= CronDatetime) //should be true but its always false
{
   //send email
}
```

My cron expression is = `"44 12 11 12 *"; run at 11 dec at 12:44 pm`

I am using [NCrontab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) library.

**Code:**

```
var cronExpression = CrontabSchedule.Parse("44 12 11 12 *");
var CronDatetime = cronExpression.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now); // returns 2023-12-11 12:44:00 pm
if(DateTime.Now >= CronDatetime) //always false 
{
   //send email
}
```

Now the problem is that the code below always returns the future date time based on cron expression and hence I am not able to send email once the time is reached:

```
var CronDatetime = cronExpression.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now); // returns 2023-12-11 12:44:00 pm
```

How can I send email once the time is reached based on cron expression?

Comment: Don't you have a Date in the past, what is relevant for sending the email? Some Creation or Update-Date to use as base for the next Occurence Date

Comment: @Turo I would like to send the email when the cron expression reaches current date nd time but the library always returns the future date

Comment: If your job runs every hour maybe you could use `cronExpression.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))`

Comment: @Turo once in a month at specific time not every hour.

Comment: "I have a background service which runs every hour" you wrote!

Comment: @Turo Yes there is a background service which runs every hour but this background service fetches data from a database table containing the cron expression to determine when to send an email. Sending email is dependent on Cron Expression date and time

Comment: What type of application is this? You might want to try Hangfire https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: @CharlesHan I am already using background service of .net core. Don’t see any use of Hangfire as Ncrontab helps me to parse cron expression nd return datetime object

Comment: If the next occurrence returns a future date, it means you have passed the current date, so you should send the emails. However, because the background process runs every hour, it will keep sending the emails unless you have some sort of mechanism to stop that. I guess you only want to send the email when the occurrence just becomes the next future date. So the solution might be to save the last occurrence date and then check if the occurrence has changed.

Comment: @CharlesHan Can you please elaborate your last 3 lines of saving the last occurrence date and checking if the occurrence changed?